# How to delete ALL field 3 duplicate lines

Tags: linux, duplicates, extract

I have the following file format:

```
[root@alpha ~]# cat file
AA BB 174
XY KJ 174
GG HY 174
XD HM 73
TT UJ 252
LL HP 252
QW ER 252
[root@alpha ~]#
```

I need to delete all lines duplicate by field 3. At the end only `XD HM 73` should be extracted and valid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sort -k3 file | uniq -f 2 -u
```

---

### Explanation:

*I write the long form of the options to help to understand*

```
sort --key=3 file
```

Sort `file` by the field **3**

---

```
uniq --skip-fields=2 --unique
```

Filter unique lines avoiding to compare the first **2** fields